# Is is possible to train on Hypergraphs in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, graphs

I know that vanilla [Keras](https://keras.io/) doesn't support operations with graphs.

For example, the [Spektral](https://graphneural.network/getting-started/) library, based on Keras API, provides some layers to work with simple graphs. However, it doesn't support graphs with multi-node connections (i.e. hypergraphs).

Is there any way to train a deep learning model on the hypergraph input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, deep learning on hypergraphs is still a relatively new area, so I don't think there's any ready-made solution for hypergraphs. I did find [this repo](https://github.com/Josh-Payne/deep-hyperedges), which implements some models in keras to accompany a recent paper on hypergraph learning, but it is hardly a library.

You may also check out [this paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=ryeHuJBtPH), which cites a pair of techniques for converting a hypergraph to a graph:

> Notably, previous methods [for hypergraph learning] typically decompose the hyperedge into pair-wise relationships where the decomposition methods can be divided into two categories: explicit and implicit. For instance, given a hyperedge (v_1,v_2,v_3), the explicit approach would decompose it directly into three edges, $(v_1,v_2), (v_2,v_3), (v_1,v_3)$, while the implicit approach would add a hidden node $e$ representing the hyperedge before decomposition, i.e., $(v_1,e),(v_2,e),(v_3,e)$.

If you're okay with doing this, then there are a few options besides Spektral:

[Deep Graph Library](https://docs.dgl.ai/index.html) provides a Tensorflow.keras compatible API, although their documentation seems to favor PyTorch.

There is also [Graph Nets](https://github.com/deepmind/graph_nets), which is built on top of Tensorflow.keras, although it's quite bare-bones at the moment.